# Limiting value of autocorrelation of wide-sense stationary process

Tags: autocorrelation, random-process, stationary

Let random process $X$ is wide-sense stationary process. Where could I find the source or verification of the statement that, when the limiting value of autocorrelation $\lim_{\tau\rightarrow\infty}R_X(\tau)$ exist, $\lim_{\tau\rightarrow\infty}R_X(\tau)=\mu_X^2$.

This is mentioned in the [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/244548/119748) of [*Relationship between autocorrelation function and mean of random process*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244527/relationship-between-autocorrelation-function-and-mean-of-random-process), and also in the document [http://web.ntpu.edu.tw/~yshan/chapter6_han.pdf](http://web.ntpu.edu.tw/%7Eyshan/chapter6_han.pdf) on p.64.

(edited from here) I saw some related writings such as [Does the auto-correlation function of stationary random process always converge?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51877/does-the-auto-correlation-function-of-stationary-random-process-always-converge) or [Random process $X(t)$ with autocorrelation function given find the mean and the variance](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34471/random-process-xt-with-autocorrelation-function-given-find-the-mean-and-the), but still I do not see mathematical derivation of the relationship $\lim_{\tau\rightarrow\infty}R_X(\tau)=\mu_X^2$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the auto-correlation function of stationary random process always converge?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51877/does-the-auto-correlation-function-of-stationary-random-process-always-converge)

Comment: Also related: [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/34471/4298).

Comment: Duplicate of [question asked on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/560824/6633).  See also https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/34471/235.

Comment: Thanks. @MattL. that is useful, but I want to find mathematical derivation of the relationship. :)

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yeah, I deleted that in the other forum. Thanks for your reply.