# Autocorrelation-properties

Tags: autocorrelation

How do we go about proving the property that entails; If X(t) is ergodic with no periodic components the autocorrelation converges to square of the mean as the time difference(τ) approaches infinity

= √→∞ () Proof : Since {X(t)} is a stationary process, then as  → ∞,() ( + ) are independent and  = [()] () = [( + )()] lim→∞() = lim→∞ [( + )()]

=lim→∞ [( + )][()] = lim→∞  = ^2

⇒  = √(lim→∞ ()) ∴ [()] = √(lim→∞ ())

This is how I proved the property, however I thought there was a more rigorous approach.

I would also like to know how we would work with the converse ( the presence of periodic components) when given only the autocorrelation.

Comment: Take a look at these two related posts: [1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/34471/4298) and [2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/51879/4298).

Comment: Thanks, I have however my question is still not answered thus the reason I posted the question.